# Javascript Timing: How do I execute a function every 5, 7, and 8 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timing

Let's say I have a function `log()`

```
var log = function(i) {
    console.log('Executing at time: ' + i);
}
```

And I want to execute `log()` on an interval, every x, y, and z seconds?

Let's arbitrarily set x, y, and z to 5, 7, and 8.

```
var x = 5;
var y = 7;
var z = 8;
```

And every x, y, and z seconds I want to call `log()`:

```
// Every 5 seconds:
log(x);
// Every 7 seconds:
log(y);
// Every 8 seconds:
log(z);
```

I could use try using three `setTimeout()`s to run these functions alone. But wait, javascript isn't asynchronous, so the execution of one `setTimeout()` will prevent the execution the other two... Hmm...

I could calculate the difference in the times, so that the delay caused by the first `setTimeout()` won't break the timing of the second and third:

```
// x is at 5 seconds, run 5000 milliseconds after the start
setTimeout(function() {  log(x); }, 5000);
// y is at 7 seconds after start, or 2000 milliseconds after x is done
setTimeout(function() {  log(y); }, 2000);
// z is at 7 seconds after start, or 1000 milliseconds after y is done
setTimeout(function() {  log(z); }, 1000);
```

But the timing would never be exactly right, as the execution of my `log()` function will take at least a small amount of time. Also, this get's messy when I try and add more `log()` commands in, or when I try and repeat the entire process at a set interval.

I could use a loop, count the seconds, and on the x, y, and zth second, execute my commands:

```
var i = 0;
while(i<10) {
    // wait 1 second (pointless function, don't know a better way to wait a second)
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(' ... '); }, 1000);
    i++;

    // execute x, y, or z depending on what time it is
    switch(i) {
        case 4: 
            log(x);
        case 6: 
            log(y);
        case 7: 
            log(z);
    }
}
```

But this method of 'counting', where I execute a useless command using setTimeout(), really just bothers me as inefficient.

Is there a better way to measure time in javascript, and have a function execute at certain times in the future? The key for me is that it's not just "run `log()` every 5 seconds", because I understand that. It's "run `log()` at times x, y and z" that confuses me.

Comment: Why not just `setInterval(func1, 5000); setInterval(func2, 7000); setInterval(func3, 8000);`?

Comment: There's no way to make the timing exactly perfect with JS. `setInterval` and `setTimeout` are only guaranteed to *try* to run the function *after* the interval has elapsed. They don't enforce that *exactly* the interval has elapsed.

Comment: Since you're concerned about the time delay introduced by the routine itself, perhaps a web worker would help here?  I.e., each 5, 7, and 8 seconds, you pass the routine out to a worker which will not prevent execution of the other calls.

Comment: Read through the middle section of my post. Because doing those commands in series would mean func1 runs at 5 seconds in, func2 runs at 12 seconds in, and func3 runs at 20 seconds in.

Comment: @Josh Eh? Why is that?

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting Mark, I've never used a 'worker' before, can you point me to some documentation?

Comment: `setTimeout` is asynchronous (won't wait for the function to execute), so you do not need to compute those differences at all

Comment: Just creates a system with function callbacks that calculates the timer setups for you. with callbacks you won't lose accuracy as it continues through iterations.

Comment: *"But wait, javascript isn't asynchronous [...]"*. JavaScript *is (can be)* asynchronous, but it is not concurrent.

Comment: Thats awesome Bergi! I assumed that the second and third setTimeout()s wouldn't execute until the first was done. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function "setInterval". Here is a example:

```
var interval1Id = setInterval(function(){
    console.log("logging every 5 seconds");
},5000);

var interval2Id = setInterval(function(){
    console.log("logging every 7 seconds");
},7000);

var interval3Id = setInterval(function(){
   console.log("logging every 8 seconds");
},8000);
```

Variables "intervalXId" are saved just in case you want to stop any interval.

Comment: Why should the OP use `setInterval` instead? Please explain how it solves the problem.

Comment: When you use "setTimeout" you are delaying the execution of a piece of code, but when you use "setInteval" you are saying that you want to execute that piece of code every X time.

Comment: I know the difference between `setInterval` and `setTimeout`. I asked how it solves the OP's problem.

Comment: I understand now what do you mean.  You are talking about `setInterval` or `setTimeout` are not perfect and they don't execute exactly every x seconds, right?. You right, if you want to execute exactly every X second this doesn't  answer the question, because it will have always a delay.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to set a timer function that's called every second and keeps a count of how many seconds have elapsed; if the count is a multiple of 5, 7, or 8, the timer function calls the function you want to execute.

Comment: That is what I discussed in the post. Doesn't that seem kind of inefficient?

If I were to use that method, is there a proper way to 'count' the time? As in, other than calling a useless function inside of setTimeout()?

Comment: I think this approach is fine. Your basic issue is you need to set up a loop, so you need to chain functions to execute at 5 7 8 seconds and I assume at 8 seconds in the cycle begins anew, yes? So filtering from a function that runs every second makes sense, or you can create a chain that executes function1, waits 5 seconds, executes function2, waits 2 seconds, executes function3, waits 1 second, executes function1 (repeat).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the next timeout inside the previous one:

```
// x is at 5 seconds, run 5000 milliseconds after the start
setTimeout(function() {
  log(x);
  setTimeout(function() {
    log(y);
    setTimeout(function() {
      log(z);
    }, 1000);
  }, 2000);

}, 5000);
```

In this way you don't schedule up front all the timeouts, but just one at the time, and there is less error's margin (the second timeout will start after the first is ending, and so on.

**Edit**
I missed actually that the OP wanted this repeated. In this case, you just need to have the first function expression with a name instead of an anonymous one, and call it at the end:

```
setTimeout(function entry() {
   log(x);
   setTimeout(function() {
     log(y);
     setTimeout(function() {
       log(z);
       setTimeout(entry, 5000);
     }, 1000);
   }, 2000);
 }, 5000);
```

My comment was about to avoid to nest, so you could have a promise-like approach.
Notice that it's also possible doing that with an additional function as **jm0** made, however is an additional pollution of the scope, where using function expression avoid that.

Comment: yes this is what i've been getting at. just need to put this in a loop and maybe generalize so that the function is built for you. Otherwise any functions added later will require re-chaining. Finally somebody is making sense...

Comment: You can't loop if you want have one timeout at once, scheduled only when the previous one is over. However, you could write an utility function that chain it for you.

Comment: yeah you can. see my recursive function below! teamworKed

Comment: My comment was about to avoid to nest the three functions, I missed the part that the OP wanted actually an interval. In this case you do not need an additional function, you can reuse the first one.

Comment: your edit throws off the timing. the 5000 disappears from the loop. nvm you got it. this looks pretty good

Comment: It seems that you wrote the comment before refreshing the code, I already noticed that and fixed. :)

Comment: i don't understand your point about scope pollution though. this is essentially the same technique that i did, except your "scope pollution" occurs 1 level deeper in the nest. it's something you'll have to take care to handle either way

Comment: `entry` is a function expression's name. It means, it can be accessed only from itself, so it doesn't pollute the outer scope; in your example `startTimeoutChain` is a function accessible inside itself **and** outside. To make it clear: `function foo(){}; console.log(typeof foo) // "function"` where `(function bar(){}); console.log(typeof bar) // "undefined"`. As habit, I don't pollute the scope if I can avoid it, and I don't create unnecessary functions; but it's also a question of personal taste.

Comment: well you could handle that through proper namespacing. My taste is not to have 5000 specified twice. I get your point now though, it's preventing it from ever hitting global scope

Comment: namespacing still pollute the scope, so it really depends by the context. Without it, I just propose what I generally prefer: I would avoid create a new extra function **and** pollute the scope. But, as I said, it's a matter of taste, that's also why I mentioned your answer in mine.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm a naive solution could be like this. With jQuery though if you have only these three intervals a nice solution would be to use deferrds.

```
function log (val) {
    console.log(val);
}

var intervals = [{interval: 5000, logVal: 'x', logged: false},
                 {interval: 7000, logVal: 'y', logged: false},
                 {interval: 8000, logVal: 'z', logged: false}];

var startTime;

function myLog () {
    var endTime = new Date().getTime();
    var diff = endTime - startTime;

    for (var i = 0; i < (intervals.length - 1); i++) {
        if (diff >= intervals[i].interval && diff < intervals[i+1].interval && !intervals[i].logged) {
            log(intervals[i].logVal);
            intervals[i].logged = true;
        }
    }

    // for last interval
    if (diff >= intervals[i].interval) {
        log(intervals[i].logVal);
        startTime = new Date().getTime();
        return;
    }

    // Reset Time and run again
    setTimeout(myLog, 500);
}

startTime = new Date().getTime();
setTimeout(myLog, 1000);
```

here's the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jD8zn/4/

Comment: I have generalized the solution checkout fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from ZER0's idea, I would set up a recursive timeout chain similar to this --

```
function startTimeoutChain() { //Represents 1 loop cyele

setTimeout(function() {
  log(x);
  setTimeout(function() {
    log(y);
    setTimeout(function() {
      log(z);
      startTimeoutChain(); // Begin next loop
    }, 1000);
  }, 2000);
}, 5000);

}
```

Just call that once & you should have something that is pretty robust. Even if the clock drifts, these values will be calibrated to each other because they are done with the delta of the times, essentially.

Though to be honest, I'm having a hard time understanding if you want to call these on the 5th, 7th, 8th seconds of some loop cycle or simply every 5, 7, 8 seconds independently of some master loop.

Comment: And in all honesty if I were to build this I would instead set it up as a function that takes 3 params -- 1. the master cycle length, 2. an array of the times to execute functions, 3. an array of the functions. Then in that function body you could have it setup the "timeout chain" for you instead of rigging these layers yourself. If this is one-off though, may not be worth the effort

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for. I haven't truly decided yet myself... I think I'm going to set a master loop of 10 seconds and have the 'clock' reset to zero every loop.

Comment: So in that case, all the timeouts should add up to 10000 (you would just bump up the 1000 to 3000 since that innermost value represents how long to wait before starting over after the last function is executed). Again, you can precalculate these if it makes it easier. but yea since this is recursive each run of the function represents 1 cycle... it essentially DOES reset to 0, conceptually

Comment: or scratch that -- you could add another layer of nesting after the 1000 timeout, with 2000 and no log function. That way you would hit your 5, 7, 8, then wait an extra 2 to begin again.