# JavaScript: Click anchor after set time

Tags: javascript

This is probably pretty simple, but I want to click:

```
     <a href="#" class="timed-next">
```

about every 5 seconds. Preferably javascript but I'll install Jquery if I have to.

Comment: Is there an event handler bound to that element? Because the link itself doesn't lead anywhere. Part of your question is answered here: [Javascript Timing: How do I execute a function every 5, 7, and 8 seconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20460190/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's native `HTMLElement.click()` inside a `setInterval()` callback.

```
var anchor = document.getElementsByClassName('timed-next')[0];

setInterval(function () {
  anchor.click();
}, 5000);
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/7xPxU/).